# On dimension of fibres

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know the following Theorem from literature : Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of varieties. Assume that there exists a non-empty open subset $U \subset Y$ such that for all $p \in U$, $\text{dim}(f^{-1}(p))=n$. Then $\text{dim}(X) =\text{dim}(Y) +n$.

In this context what can be said if we start with a closed subset $T \subset Y$ with codimension atleast $2$ in $Y$. Let $p \in T$, then how the above equality relation will change(i.e. what will be the relation between $\text{dim}(X), \text{dim}(Y), \text{dim}(f^{-1}(p))$? Can someone indicate a brief argument (or reference?)

Comment: What do you mean by "we start with a subset $T\subset Y$"? $T$ mysteriously disappears from your question after that point.  If you are wondering whether you can say anything just from the dimension of fibers over a subset $T$, then consider a blowup of $\mathbb{P}^n$ at a point. The exceptional fiber has dimension $n-1$, while the general fiber is a single point.

Comment: @Sergey Guminov, I have edited the question now. Can we say anything when the point $p$ is not coming from an open set of the target space and instead coming from a closed subcheme of codimension atleast $1$ of the target space...how does it affect the equality relation?

Comment: As the example of the blow-up shows, you can't say much: the fiber at a point may well have dimension $\dim(X)-1$. The best you can do is notice that the dimension of a special fiber can't be less than the dimension of the general fiber. So if the dimension of fiber is $n$ at some point, you have $\dim(X)\leqslant\dim(Y)+n$.